# How to change letters in a word from upper case to lower case or the other way around (swap case)?

Tags: vim

Instead of deleting the word and retyping all the letters once again in the opposite case, I'd like to find some smart way in Vim to solve the problem.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's

```
g~iw
```

with the cursor on the word.

Key:

- `g` flag (I couldn't find a good reference for this...)
- `~` toggle case; alternatively use `U` for to-upper or `u` for to-lower
- `iw` selects the Inner Word, i.e. the word that the cursor is on; `ip` selects the Inner Paragraph

See Michael Jakl's *[Vim Introduction and Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190228223619/https://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/vim_tutorial.html)* - concise and has some nice graphical explanations.

Comment: @martin : thanks for your help , it works . but could you explain your command a little, then we can learn more from this topic .

Comment: `g~`: This changes the case of whatever text-motion comes next. `iw` is the text motion for "inner-word", so `g~iw` changes the case of what vim defines as a word (pretty much what english defines as a word). enter `:help motion` for more info in vim.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `gu` and `gU` change all of the `{motion}` text to lower and upper case, respectively, in case you don't just want to toggle.  See `:help g~`, `:help gu`, and `:help, gU`.

Comment: does not work if the cursor is right after the word, in all other cases jumps to the start of the word after changing the case. There must be a better solution that I would like to keybind...

Comment: is there a hint about what "g" means here?

Comment: @dragonxlwang `g` just accesses several additional/extra commands, like `z`; mainly used because the availability of shortcuts was getting low

Comment: @Slava if the cursor is after the word, you would want `g~b` or `bg~iw` instead, a script that checks for characters before/after might be a more universal solution that would work, but that's not something I can hack together quickly

Comment: `Vim Introduction and Tutorial` link seems broken

Comment: The `Vim Introduction and Tutorial` link has happily been **fixed** with the URL pointing to the _Wayback Machine_ of the _Internet Archive_.  +1 for the best reference I've _**ever**_ seen on Vim, and I wish I could +1 to whoever fixed the link, too!

Answer (score 37):

`g~` followed by a "motion" will flip the case of the letters.

`gU` will upper-case them

`gu` will lower case them

So

`g~w` will flip the case of the letters to the end of the current word.

`guG` will lower case the letters to the end of the file

`gU$` will upper case the letters to the end of the current line.

Comment: and here i was fussing with individual '~' key presses all this time!

Answer (score 27):

you can do this in normal mode: `vEU` (having the cursor at the beginning of the word or pressing `b` to move it there)

`v` - go to visual

`E` - go to end of the word

`U` - make the visual selection uppercase

Instead of the `U` you can do `u` for lowercase or `~` for case flip.

Comment: if the cursor is in the middle of a word you can use `viwU` or `viwu`.  `iw` means 'the entire word'

Answer (score 9):

~ (tilde) key. Should change the case of whatever is under the cursor. Works in normal and visual mode.

Answer (score 7):

You can select the word with visual mode (`viw`) and press `~`, it switches case for all letters in the word.

Answer (score 2):

I would liek to emphasize that, in order to achiving switch the upper/lower case of a word, **it depends on what is the exact position of the cursor.**

**if the cursor is now at the first character of the word**, **you can use `g~w`**:

`g` stands for you want to do some operation in some scope(while the `w` definese the exact scope;
`~` means you want to switch the upper&lower case(you can substitue `~` with `U`/`u`, which means you want to switch the word into upper case/lower case);
`w` means you want to do the case switch from the cursor to the end of the word;

**if the cursor is now in the middle of the word, not the very beginning of it**, **you can use `g~iw`**:

`iw` means you want to do the case swith for the word in which the corsor is now located.

Answer (score -2):

Shift + F3 flips the word(s) between all uppercase, just the first letter and all lowercase. Has changed my life

Comment: I think the downvote was because it appears to be out of the context of `vim`.   If it is part of vim, it's not clear if it's some kind of vim desktop gui, or created by a vi pluggin, or something else - so they really should have also explained this and/or asked you to clarify your answer when they downvoted.